# How to giver border-bottom to active tab

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a tab, which on click I want to give some color to the bottom

Initially there is a line (div) I have created and give it some css so it is coming at the bottom,
Now when I click to a particular tab I am changing color of my text, but I also want to give some bottom border.

for that I am just using the below css

```css
.active {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  height: 4px;
  width: 9%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

but here I have to give fixed with which is causing issue,I want it to take the full width of text.

**My code**

```js
{
  common_data.map((li, index) => ( <
    div key = {
      index
    }
    className = "d-flex menu_group"
    onClick = {
      () => menu_click(index)
    }
    onMouseEnter = {
      () => mouse_enter(index)
    }
    onMouseLeave = {
      mouse_leave
    } >
    <
    i className = {
      index === menu_state ?
      li.icon + '-fill icon_menu_fill' :
        index === idi ?
        li.icon + '-line icon_menu_line onHover' :
        li.icon + '-line icon_menu_line'
    } > < /i> <
    div className = {
      index === menu_state ?
      'name_active' :
        index === idi ?
        'onHover name_not_active' :
        'name_not_active'
    } > {
      li.menu
    } <
    /div> <
    div className = {
      index === menu_state ? 'active d-flex flex-column' : ''
    } > < /div> <
    /div>
  ))
}
```

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-dew-yo9du?file=/src/App.js)

I think I am missing a small part, the way I am doing is just a hack-around, I want to do it in proper way.

Comment: tied adding a border to the bottom only and giving the bottom a color? (border-bottom: height solid color)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-paper-liz2n)

Added `position: relative;` on `.menu_group` and `width: 100%;` on `.active`

Add some padding on tab if you want a wider underline.

Comment: up that worked, but is that correct way, because suppose If i want to do some transition to make it look fancy, it will not look good

Comment: Depends on what kind of transitions you're going for, honestly. There's usually no definite right or wrong when it comes to css.